# how to show windows service exception in GUI Message?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-services

How i show GUI message show box for Windows Service.

I got one link on MSDN but no idea from where I start my work, please guide me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yvesdolc/archive/2009/08/20/do-you-still-use-the-messagebox-api-in-your-windows-service.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your needs are limited to dialog boxes, check out the [WTSSendMessage function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383842%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: i know this function but no idea how to implements.
Please Give me some Demo in c#. because i got the demo in C++ but it's very complex to understand...

Answer (score 2):

You can't show UI from a service. Services run in session 0 and there is no desktop. What's more services run when there are no logged on users. Again there is no desktop.

You have a couple of options:

1. Log your messages rather than attempt to show them.
2. Have a helper application that runs as a standard user app on the logged on user's desktop. This app can show UI. Communicate between the service and the app via an IPC mechanism of your choice.

Comment: I need some proper example.. this think every one say..

check this link this service work properly..

http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2004/12/03/488.aspx

here windows service send the GUI message on Desktop 

but i want show services exception on Desktop in GUI message

Comment: The article you cite was written before session 0 isolation was invented. The method described in that article no longer works. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yvesdolc/archive/2009/08/20/do-you-still-use-the-messagebox-api-in-your-windows-service.aspx) describes some alternatives (includes sample code).

Comment: Here is a newer link to the article mentioned by RaymondChen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/yvesdolc/do-you-still-use-the-messagebox-api-in-your-windows-service